# White gap between Bootstrap navbar and background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

There's a white gap between Bootstrap navbar and Background as visible from the image below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7K5M.png]

Anyone have an idea how to get rid of this?

Here's my code

```
<body>

    <div class="navbar">

        <div class="navbar-inner">

                <a class="brand" href="#">CrayOns</a>

                    <ul class="nav">

                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

    </ul>

    </div>  

</div>

<center>

            <p>Currently under maintenance <br/>
```

ALso, does anyone have any idea on how to change the color of the buttons on bootstrap?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

#### Why am I seeing this extra spacing?

If you're using an un-configured version of Bootstrap, `.navbar`, by default, has this set:

```
margin-bottom: @baseLineHeight;
```

where

```
@baseLineHeight: 20px;
```

which is probably causing the behavior you're seeing.

To get rid of this, simply add

```
.navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

to any stylesheet loaded after bootstrap.

Sources:

[navbar.less, line 12](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L12)

[variables.less, line 53](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L53)

#### How can I change the colors of the boxes?

The easiest way would be modifying the .less files. Luckily, the creators behind Bootstrap make this super easy through the [configuration page.](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) The relevant variables to you are the 'background' and 'text' variables under '*Form states & alerts*'. Note that changing the colors here will affect all other elements that use the 'warning,' 'info,' etc. nomenclature for determining color. For instance, labels & badges.

If you'd like to change just the *button* colors, I'd probably leave Bootstrap unmodified and write extra css rules to your files. For instance, I might target `.btn-warning` to apply the appropriate color to just the button.

If you're doing this in less, it'd simply be a matter of creating a new variable and assigning the color to that variable (note: while it is true that using variables here isn't necessary, I'm suggesting a method of good practice)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for your help!  Any idea on how to fix the buttons?

Comment: @craycraycrayons, I updated my answer to talk about button colors.

Answer (score -1):

In the div where is the container you should add a style like the next line:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid"  style="margin-top:-15px">
```